# pound ssl offloading and haproxy balance source

Tags: haproxy, pound

I have pound in front of haproxy for ssl termination. haproxy has a frontend that balance with source algorithm.

The problem is that the ssl connections from pound are balanced to the one server meanwhile plain http from the same client is sent to another server because haproxy sees the pound ip as the source.

Is there a way to tell pound to act as transparent proxy or I have to upgrade to 1.5-dev of haproxy (that supports ssl) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have setup HAProxy 1.5-dev19 with SSL support enabled and works great.